# WPF Custom Control - How to properly loop through and display child content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Attempting to write a custom control which permits a collection of children content.  The end goal is to have some functional filtering of the child elements based on custom attached dependency properties; however, before getting that far, any attempts I've made to collect and re-display child UIElements have ended in exceptions during XAML parsing/display.

I have a class `CustomFilter : Control` which has an associated default style in a nearby xaml file.  It has a dependency property for Children, which currently collect the child elements in a UIElementCollection.

I believe my problem may be how I am attempting to render the collection of children.  The only way I know of looping through content in XAML involves using an ItemsControl, to which I am passing my Children collection as the ItemsSource, which feels rather backwards (using UIElements as data models?)

Afterwards, we attempt to render the elements via a content presenter inside of the ItemTemplate.  I've seen in many other examples which render control children using content presenters, so I expect this is probably at least partially correct (though all only using single elements).

The sample class

```
  [ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
  public class CustomFilter : Control
  {
    static CustomFilter()
    {
      DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomFilter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomFilter)));
    }

    public CustomFilter()
    {
      Children = new UIElementCollection(this, this);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Children), typeof(UIElementCollection), typeof(CustomFilter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(RefreshFilter));
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
    public UIElementCollection Children
    {
      get { return (UIElementCollection)GetValue(ChildrenProperty); }
      private set { SetValue(ChildrenProperty, value); }
    }
  }
```

The sample template

```
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomFilter}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomFilter}">
          <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Children}">
              <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel>
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                  </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
              </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
          </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

The use case

```
  <local:CustomFilter>
    <TextBlock Text="X"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Y"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Z"/>
  </local:CustomFilter>
```

Attempting to run use this control whatsoever causes it to fail when it reaches the ItemsControl, without reaching the ItemTemplate, with the following exception:

`ArgumentException: Specified Visual is already a child of another Visual or the root of a CompositionTarget.`

I've attempted to create a wrapper class for the Children, passing one child to each instance of the wrapper, and binding to that as an ItemsSource - it successfully loops through the ItemTemplate, but attempting to use the ContentPresenter there on the wrapped child element provides me with the following exception instead:

`ArgumentException: Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual.`

Comment: Why aren't you inheriting from itemscontrol? This thing kind of sounds like an itemscontrol which filters it's content. Is it just filtering you're doing? Because you could do that in the viewmodel layer with a collectionview.

Comment: @Andy the concept crossed my mind, but I wanted to try without inheriting first, just to make sure I could do it right from the basics.  I definitely wanted to do so later on, to make use of the feature to define your own panel and other stylings, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an `UIElementCollection` instead of a `List<UIElement>`? You are not supposed to bind to an `UIElementCollection` in a template.

Your example should work if you define a `List<UIElement>` dependency property:

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Children))]
public class CustomFilter : Control
{
    static CustomFilter()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(CustomFilter), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(CustomFilter)));
    }

    public CustomFilter()
    {
        SetValue(ChildrenPropertyKey, new List<UIElement>());
    }

    private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey ChildrenPropertyKey =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
              nameof(Children),
              typeof(List<UIElement>),
              typeof(CustomFilter),
              new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new List<UIElement>())
            );
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ChildrenProperty =
        ChildrenPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public List<UIElement> Children
    {
        get { return (List<UIElement>)GetValue(ChildrenProperty); }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was unaware of the implications of using a UIElementCollection... however, I did eventually go through and replace it with a List<UIElement>.  While I have found a solution to my overall problem which works differently, I will accept your answer - given some time to try it out.